# Java map with tuple as key, remove/get by tuple key

Tags: java, treemap

I have scenario where I would like to have a sorted map with a tuple as key:

```
var scheduledRunnables = new TreeMap<Tuple<Integer, String>, Runnable>(Comparator.comparing(Tuple::getKey));
```

When adding, I want to add a tuple:

```
scheduledRunnables.put(new Tuple<>(order, taskName), task);
```

When sorting, I want it to be sorted by the order integer, since that determines order of execution of the runnables. I do not necessarily know the value of the variable `taskName`. When calling `get`, I want to only supply the order integer, because of the same reason as previously stated. When calling `put`, I want to take the entire pair into consideration. So something like this:

```
scheduledRunnables.put(new Tuple<>(1, "Some task"), () -> System.out.println("asdf"));
scheduledRunnables.get(1).run(); // Should output 'asdf'
scheduledRunnables.put(new Tuple<>(1, "Some task"), () -> System.out.println("qwerty"));
scheduledRunnables.get(1).run(); // Should output 'qwerty'
scheduledRunnables.remove(1).run(); // Should output 'qwerty' and remove from map
```

The `Tuple` class is just a data holder that looks like this:

```
@Data
public class Tuple<K, V> {

    private final K key;
    private V value;

    public Tuple(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

How would this be implemented? Is is possible without making a custom implementation of the SortedMap interface? Is there a better way to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make you `value` not relevant (its just a meta information). So its not needed for initializing the class (optional parameter) and not taken into account when using `hashCode` or `equals`:

```
public class Tuple<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Comparable<Tuple<K, V>> {
    private final K key;
    private V value;

    public Tuple(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Tuple(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return key.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj == this || (obj instanceof Tuple) && key.equals(((Tuple) obj).key);
    }

    public int compareTo(Tuple<K, V> other) {
        return key.compareTo(other.key);
    }
}
```

I've also made `Tuple` comparable, which will just compare the keys, so you can create your `TreeMap` without a custom `Comparator` like this:

```
var scheduledRunnables = new TreeMap<Tuple<Integer, String>, Runnable>();
```

You then can call your get with:

```
Runnable runnable = scheduledRunnables.get(new Tuple<>(1));
```

Comment: So simple and solves my use case exactly, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is confusing. There may be multiple runnables in the map with Integer 1 and you'll just arbitrarily get one of them. This is abuse of a map.

Comment: @Michael it depends, really, if `taskName` is only a meta value (like I assumed) then this is perfectly valid use of a `TreeMap` in my opinion

Comment: Then don't use a tuple. Use a `Task`.

Comment: @Michael It's just a naming thing then, I simply used the one from OPs question, but maybe `Task` would really suit better in this case

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, just maintain two maps.

```
Map<Integer, Runnable> idToRunnable;
Map<Integer, String> idToName;
```

Or use the tuple for the value rather than the key:

```
Map<Integer, Tuple<String, Runnable>>
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, I want the world tuple to override the hello tuple.

Comment: Or `Map<Integer, NameAndRunnable>`.

Comment: Well this was by far the easiest solution, thank you

Comment: Because I think that the OP is learning. About the `Tuple` requirement, I have also some doubts but well.

Comment: @davidxxx fair enough. I would never use a `Tuple` personally, outside of maybe some intermediate stream operations where defining a specific data holder class is overkilll, but I'm not completely averse to it here.

Answer (score 1):

> When calling `get`, I want to only supply the order integer

That has some hidden assumptions that aren't being enforced by your code.  If you're using a Tuple as your key, then getting an entry out of the map by just one *part* of that Tuple has the possibility of returning multiple entries.  By way of example, consider this simplified code:

```
Map<Tuple<Integer, String>, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(new Tuple<>(1, "Foo"), "First");
map.put(new Tuple<>(1, "Bar"), "Second");

? = map.get(1); // What should this return?
```

That `get()`, if you only cared about part of the Tuple, would be expected to return *multiple* values.

If you don't care about part of your Tuple, then you shouldn't be using Tuples as keys to your map, since keys are expected to be distinct, but *parts* of keys are not.  Without knowing more about your use case, I'm not sure what the best option is for you, though.

Comment: The assumption I'm making is that this will return "Second", since the string value is metadata and not important, adding 1 again will override the first value. However I completely agree withyour last point, I might reconsider this.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a String as a key, where String will be a concatenation of Integer + String (perhaps add a "_ " as a spacer in case String has some digits.) This way the order will be handled automatically, just implement similar mechaninsm to look up the values.

`var scheduledRunnables = new TreeMap<String, Runnable>();`

Then, if you need to get all values with "1" in the key, you can use
`scheduledRunnables.keys()` and get those starting with "1".